# payment page - total not correct when using Tax

Tags: webform-civicrm, taxes

I have setup a webform to take registrations and payments for events. I have enabled tax to be 10% and have calculated the cost of each event to be 10% less, so Civi will add on the tax to each line item (i assume that this is the only way Civi Tax works). The total is $0.1 by out. Here is why:

$75 - 10% = $68.18 (I have set the Participant Fee to $68.18)

$68.18 * 3 events = 204.54
Add the tax: 204.54 * 0.1 = 20.454 ($20.45, rounded)

$20.45 + 204.54 = $224.99

[image]

Edit: Seems like a similar issue to https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9711 & https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/9710

Are these patches still relevant?

Comment: Two quick thoughts: That does not look like the latest webform_civicrm? Also $75 -10% is $67.50 -> but I get that you need $68.18 -> have you tried giving participant fee two more decimals?

Comment: CMS/Civi/webform_civicrm are up to date. Adding 2 more decimals fixed the issue when duplicating the last 2 decimals. ie: 68.18 = 68.1818. Thanks KarinG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sales Taxes in CiviCRM are added on checkout - so if you want to get to nice rounded numbers you may need to give your participant_fee a few more decimals.

Glad that worked for you Ben!

Comment: Hi @KarinG - I am having the same issue on CiviCRM 5.5. The amount for unit price is $58 inclusive of GST 5.27 - It works fine when the unit is 1 but if I add 2 it becomes 116.01. Is this still a bug in CiviCRM?